# PaaS Offerings for Node.js

Tags: node.js, digital-ocean, paas, linode

I keep finding blogs and articles that list Digital Ocean and Linode as having PaaS offerings for Node.js. This is bothering me because I've hosted apps on both Linode and Digital Ocean and although they do have one-click installs of Node.js or MongoDB stacks, You are still responsible as a developer for securing your infrastructure, managing it, upgrading it, etc.

[Modulus](https://modulus.io/nodejs) is something i've been looking at that seems to be a truly PaaS platform for Node.js.

Am i misunderstanding the definition of PaaS or are all these blogs/articles talking about Digital Ocean and Linode having PaaS offerings for Node.js actually incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

I align with your definition that VPS ≠ PaaS. Modulus has turned into Xervo. And Xervo has turned into dust. All the hip Node kids are with [zeit now](https://zeit.co/now). This question is product related, not sure if this OK here on SO.

Comment: Damn Zeit now looks legit AF!

Answer (score 0):

Digital Ocean is an IaaS (infrastructure as a service) which means that they offer you VMs (virtual machines) that you have to control (manage, update etc).

I read and article that they raised some money to offer PaaS offerings also.

PaaS is Platform as a service. Most notable may be Heroku which will run the app for you, but won't give you access to the underlying VM. Your headache is only the app and they manage the rest.

I can't say much about the individual offerings as one service may offer both PaaS and IaaS, but I hope I was clear about the difference.